# How do I perform a function on multiple rows of data which are factored by the column they are in R?

Tags: arrays, r, function, data.table

I have a table in a file with many rows which I have read into R using

```
data <-read.table("path/to/data.txt",header=TRUE, sep="\t",row.names=1)
            A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
    Row1    1      3    2     3     2     6    
    Row2    3      2    1     3     6     7
    ...
```

I have then read this into a frame using

```
df <-data.frame(data)
```

I would like to perform a function() to compare the A samples against the B samples for each row,

```
function(A,B)
```

but I am unsure how to specify only the A's and only the B's from the data frame for each row - is there a way to do this all at once for the whole data table? Do I have to read the data into a frame or can I work straight from the initial read.table data?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean with 'compare the A samples against the B samples'? What is your expected result?

Comment: specifically, I would like to perform the wilcoxon.test function on each row, but i'm not sure how to specify the entries, the syntax is `wilcox.test(sampA,sampB)` and i want to perform it on each row of the table

Comment: For Row1, sampA would be the three entries under A1, A2, A3 in the first row (1,3,2) and sampB would be the three entries under B1, B2, B3 in the first row (3,2,6), but i would like to do this for every row in the file

Comment: i'm new to R, and i've looked everywhere, but i haven't been able to find out how to specify specific columns and rows, i know to call the first row i can use `data[1,]` but i can't find the syntax for calling only the first 3 columns or the last 3 columns for example and i also tried using factor, `factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2))` but i'm stuck as to how i specify the 1's and the 2's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(001) # Generating some data
DF <- data.frame(A1=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                 A2=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                 A3=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                 B1=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                 B2=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                 B3=sample(1:9, 10, T))


sampA <- DF[,grep('A', names(DF))]  # Sample with columns A
sampB <- DF[,grep('B', names(DF))]  # Sample with columns B


lapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i){
  wilcox.test(as.numeric(sampA[i,]), as.numeric(sampB[i,]), exact=FALSE )
})  # Performing the test
```

The result looks like this:

```
[[1]]

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  as.numeric(sampA[i, ]) and as.numeric(sampB[i, ]) 
W = 3, p-value = 0.6579
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0 


[[2]]

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  as.numeric(sampA[i, ]) and as.numeric(sampB[i, ]) 
W = 0, p-value = 0.0722
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0 


[[3]]

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  as.numeric(sampA[i, ]) and as.numeric(sampB[i, ]) 
W = 6, p-value = 0.6579
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

I only showed the first 3 results, the complete list length is 10 since `DF` has 10 rows.

Comment: thanks @Jilber - each htest output seems to save itself to a different entry in your example to [[1]], [[2]] and [[3]]. I would like to save the output to a text file and was wondering how i would do this as I can't use write.table for this. Is it possible to grep out the W and p-values instead from the htest result and stick that into a frame that i can save to a text file?

Comment: hi - i just worked it out and used `data.frame(unlist(output))`. thanks again!

Comment: @user1637359, Glad to be useful. You can upvote the answer as well.